# Is there a way to replace the first two occurrences of a value in a string?

Tags: powershell

I am going to be as clear with my question as I can.
I might be missing something very obvious here but I just don't know how to find a solution...

I have a string and I would like to replace the first two occurrences of ":" with "/":

***String:***

`$string = 2020:10:07  08:45:49`

***Desired String:***

`2020/10/07 08:45:49`

I have tried using `.Replace` as seen below:

`$string = $string.Replace([regex]":","/",2)`

But I am given this error every time:

`Cannot find an overload for "replace" and the argument count: "3".`

I have seen others use `.Replace` in this way before so I'm not sure what is so different about my usage. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is .net-based language.
`String` does not have overload method `Replace` with anything like `count` argument [in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.replace), but Python's string [does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

You can use this:

```
$string = '2020:10:07  08:45:49'
#Replace 2+ spaces you have in source with single space
$string = $string -replace '\s+', ' '

# Variant 0 - Best - ALWAYS use proper types. There is DateTime type to use for Dates and Times!    
    #Exact parse by format to DateTime object
    $dt = [DateTime]::ParseExact($string, 'yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
    #Convert DateTime to String
    $result = $dt.ToString('yyyy\/MM\/dd hh:mm:ss')
```

---

.Net's `String.Split` has optional parameter `count` that means *split no more than into # pieces*. You can use it:

```
# Variant1
$result = [string]::Join('/',$string.Split(':', 3))

# Variant2
$result = $string.Split(':', 3) -join '/'
```

Comment: Variant2 is clever. 

Answer (score 1):

`String.Replace()` does not support regex patterns, nor does it accept a maximum count.

Use the `-replace` regex operator instead:

```
$string = '2020:10:07  08:45:49'
$string -replace '(?<=^[^:]*):(.*?):','/$1/'
```

This will replace only the first and second occurrence of `:` with `/`

---

Specifically for date/time representations, you may want to parse it as such, at which point you can easily re-format it:

```
$string = '2020:10:07  08:45:49'
$datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($string, "yyyy:MM:dd  HH:mm:ss", $null)

# Now we can create a new string with the desired format
Get-Date $datetime -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss'

# This might be easier than figuring out regex patterns
'{0:dd/MMM/yyyy-HH.mm.ss}' -f $datetime
```

Comment: I ran this and it replaced all of the occurrences of ```:```

Comment: @thesuperiorspider sorry about that, I clicked too fast ^_^ updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: With regexp it should be incredibly slow when using on huge bunch of data. I's recommend avoid regexps in such cases. But the expression itself is wonderful, cool!